# Error:fatal: Not a git repository: '.' when I use gitolite Hooks post-receive to auto deploy code

Tags: git, ubuntu, hook, autodeploy

My English is not very good. Please bear with me.

I had search this question on stackoverflow and google.But also can't solve this question.

I just want to build a auto deploy enviroment through git hooks.But it's doesn't work.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 server as server on one computer,I call it ***PC-Ser***.
And I use a Windows 7 PC as client on other computer,I call it ***PC-C***.

And I install gitolite on ***PC-Ser*** with:

> 1. apt-get install gitolite
> 2. addgroup gitolite
> 3. adduser --disabled-password --home /home/gitolite --ingroup gitolite gitolite
> 4. su gitolite
> 5. gl-setup /tmp/user.pub

Then I

```
"git clone gitolite@PC-Ser:gitolite-admin"
```

on ***PC-C***.

I create a repo named autoDeploy through edit gitolite.conf file and push it.This is **gitolite.conf**:

```
repo    gitolite-admin
        RW+ = admin

repo    autoDeploy
        RW+ = @all
```

After that,I do someting on ***PC-Ser***:

```
cd /var/www
git clone /home/gitolite/repositories/autoDeploy.git
```

And then I edit **/home/gitolite/repositories/autoDeploy.git/hooks/post-receive**:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/autoDeploy
pwd >> /log/pwd.log
git push /home/gitolite/autoDeploy>> /log/push.log 2>&1
echo "finish" >> /log/finish.log
whoami >> /log/user.log
```

And then, I creat a test.txt on ***PC-C***.autoDeploy and I push it.

But /var/www/autoDeploy have not pulled.It does not work.

There have this on ***PC-Ser***'s log:

/log/pwd.log:

```
/var/www/autoDeploy
```

/log/push.log:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

/log/finish.log:

```
finish
```

/log/user.log:

```
gitolite
```

I try run the /home/gitolite/repositories/autoDeploy.git/hooks/post-receive by root,it's success,/var/www/autoDeploy has pulled.

Then I "su gitolite" and run /home/gitolite/repositories/autoDeploy.git/hooks/post-receive,it's also success.No error./var/www/autoDeploy has pulled success.

Please help me.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507942/git-checkout-in-post-receive-hook-not-a-git-repository