# Change Mod RewriteBase depending on domain/url

Tags: git, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, githooks

I want to change the RewriteBase depending on the domain. In a perfect world I would do this in the .htaccess itself. But my understanding is that this is impossible.

The problem is that I have a local git repo and a repo on our dev server. The repo on the dev server is within a subfolder (example.com/mysite) while localy its just example.lo.

So on the server I have to set the RewriteBase to /mysite

My question then is, what is the best sollution to solve this? We can use git hooks to trigger a bash script on the bare server repo.

Will it work to add the .htaccess to the .gitignore when the repo is --bare and using this post receive hook?:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/Users/Admin/Sites/mysite git checkout -f
```

Drop in a comment if Im unclear about anything. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of post-receive hook can work, but you might end up with a `Not a git repository '.'”` error message.

See "[Git checkout in post-receive hook: “`Not a git repository '.'`”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507942/git-checkout-in-post-receive-hook-not-a-git-repository)": you should set `GIT_DIR` too, not just `GIT_WORK_TREE`.

> The question is if it will delete the `.htaccess` file when it checks out the files, when the `.htaccess` is in the `.gitignore` file

No you won't delete it.

If you still need to update its value (depending on the domain) and version it with git, use a content filter: see "[What's the easiest way to deal with project configuration files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6826682/6309)".

Comment: The hook works. That I know. The question is if it will delete the .htaccess file when it checks out the files, when the .htaccess is in the .gitignore file? And is there a better way to do this?

One problem with this sollution is that you can never edit your .htaccess file and update it on the server through git.

Comment: @MathiasMadsenStav I have edited my answer to address your questions.